# Can you prevent Visual Studio 2013 from starting all web sites in a solution when using IIS Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

Is it possible to configure IIS Express to **not** run all the web sites in a given solution?  I have a solution with 4 web sites and I only want IIS Express to run 2 of them when I hit Start (F5) in Visual Studio 2013.  I have the solution set to only start 2 of them, the other 2 are set to None.

I went into the IIS Express config file and created a new app pool with autoStart="false" and assigned this new app pool to the sites that I do **not** want to run.  I also set the serverAutoStart attribute to false in the site tags, that I don't want to run.  These changes didn't make any difference.  The IIS Express tray interface still shows all 4 sites as running.  (Yes, I shut down Visual Studio and made sure all the iisexpress processes were dead, before restarting.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, 
By default all sites has a property called "Always start when debugging" set to True
setting this property to false will allow starting only the specific site you choose to debug.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Disable Always Start When Debugging](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TahaAmin.DisableAlwaysStartWhenDebugging) VS add-in tool.